# mailto not opening gmail compose tab

Tags: html, mailto

Im using codeigniter framework and im trying to compose an email when i click on a button. This is the code i have but its not opening browser tab like this

[image]

```
<div>
<a href="mailto:<?php echo $customer['phone']; ? 
>@mail.mightytext.net?subject=&body=<?php echo $emailBody;?>" 
class="btn btn-primary">Confirm Details with Customer</a>
</div>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: is a mailto link the best approach, not used much theses days for all the downsides.

Comment: I doubt this is related to PHP or codeigniter. If you output the generated code and put it in an HTML file does it behave the same? If so it is an HTML/gmail/browser issue.

Comment: i think its unrelated to php or codeigniter. if it was a browser issue what could be wrong?

Comment: A `mailto:` link will open in whatever application is the default email client on your visitor's device. Did you [configure your browser](https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/set-gmail-as-browser-default-email-client-ht) to send `mailto:` links to Gmail as your mail handler?

Comment: Your application does not have any direct control over what mail client is used for mailto links.

Comment: I agree, `mailto:` may use the default emailing software on your computer. You can install browser extensions to enable the intended behaviour.

Comment: Thanks guys. i configured browser like rickdenhaan suggested and it work :)